# Is there any gradle plugin to validate XML?

Tags: xml, validation, gradle, automation, gradle-plugin

I work on a project where we have xml files for code generation and we use `gradle` to build it.

I'm novice in `gradle`, but I heard that there are a lot of `plugins` that could help with routine tasks and I wonder if there are some plugins for xml simple validation (missing quotes and brackets).

I would like to get name of file and list of missings as result.

PS Tried to search in google, but couldn't find something like that.

UPD If in not so distant future full validation of xml file (tags, parameters) would be required, what should I do?

Comment: The term "validation" in the XML world has a specialized meaning: it means checking that the XML conforms with some supplied schema. A schema might say that a `p` element can contain `i` elements but not vice versa. I suspect this isn't what you are looking for: the phrase "missing quotes and brackets" suggests you just want to check if a file contains well-formed XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple to write your own

```
class XmlValidate extends DefaultTask {
    @InputFiles
    private FileCollection xmlFiles

    @InputFile
    File xsd

    void xml(Object files) {
       FileCollection fc = project.files(files)
       this.xmlFiles = this.xmlFiles == null ?  fc : this.xmlFiles.add(fc)
    }

    @TaskAction
    public void validateXml() {
        DocumentBuilder parser = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
        Validator validator = null
        if (xsd != null) {
            SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI)
            Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(xsd))
            validator = schema.newValidator()
        } 
        Set<File> failures = [] as Set
        xmlFiles.forEach {
            Document document = null
            try {
                document = parser.parse(it)
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error parsing $it", e) 
                failures << it
            } 
            if (document && validator) {
                try {
                    validator.validate(new DOMSource(document))
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("Error validating $it", e) 
                    failures << it
                } 
            } 
        }
        if (failures) throw new BuildException("xml validation failures $failures") 
    } 
}
```

Usage in build.gradle

```
task validateXml(type: XmlValidate) {
    xml ['foo.xml', 'bar.xml']
    xml fileTree(dir: 'src/main/resources/baz', include: '*.xml')
    xsd = file('path/to.xsd')
}
```

Comment: Added suggested code in projectRoot/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/XMLValidate.groovy. 

But got the following error when tried to use this task in build.gradle.
<br/>

    41: unable to resolve class BuildException 
    @ line 41, column 29.
    if (failures) throw new BuildException("xml validation failures $failures")